# Let's form groups of 3 or 4 people?

Tags: sentence-construction

Suppose a teacher wants to create study groups in his class and each group will consist of three or four people. I wonder what is the most idiomatic to say this. Can he say

> Let's form groups of three or four people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I would change about this sentence would be the usage of "Let's". "Let's" refers to everyone including the speaker. By replacing that with "Everybody", it specifies that the teacher will not be joining a group. A native speaker may also replace "form" with "get in" for a more casual tone.

> Everybody get in groups of three or four.

That being said, your original sentence near perfect and would be understood just fine.